Why is the BQ25895 default system voltage 3.5V not 3.3V?
Why is the default system voltage 3.5V, not 3.3V even though, for example, the STM32 maximum voltage is 3.6V, but nominal is 3.3V?
BQ25895 datasheet.


3.5 V is only the lower limit.
SYS is connected directly to BAT when the battery voltage is high enough. About 4.2 V is the voltage of a fully charge Li-ion battery; about 3.5 V is where it ends up when it is mostly discharged.
SYS is designed to be used for a system that originally expected to be connected to such a battery; the system must be able to handle more than 4 V, and is likely to use its own voltage regulator.

great thanks for the clarification
